# On a jailbroken iPhone, how can I run commands as root?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, system

I want to login as a root using `system` call in Xcode. I try this code without success:

```
System("su");
System("alpine");
```

or

```
System("su root");
System("alpine");
```

or

```
System("su root alpine");
```

When I google it I came to know that this is done using `NSTask` or `NSPipe`.
Can anybody tell me how it possible to run multiple `system` commands using `NSTask` and `NSPipe`?

Please give me some hints about this or another method to do this. I am using this application on jailbroken iPhone.

Some more details are [here](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=290555).

Comment: Mind that if you put your application in `/Applications` you'll already be root when your app launches.

Comment: Also mind that the iOS is a Unix operating system. And I think you cannot give an already existing process the root privileges. You can only launch new processes with higher permissions. This means you'll need auxiliary executables. (Unless you relaunch the app as root)

Comment: Also keep in mind that with `system()` it's as if you typed the exact thing you pass to it to your command-line shell. (You don't get to call it twice to pass input in.) So `system("alpine")` isn't the correct approach. And with `system()` (unlike using `fork()` and `exec()`) you don't have direct control of the I/O of the child process. What exactly are you trying to do once you "log on as root"? Because even if you manage to get a shell, `system()` will just hang your process and wait for the shell to exit. Suggested reading: `man 3 system`, `man 2 fork`, and `man 3 exec`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch something as root you may use `sudo`.

Example of it's usage in one line with the password:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Comment: This would of course require the `sudo` executable to be installed on the device.

Comment: If your iphone is jailbroken you may install sudo though Cydia.

Comment: In case you application is going to be released though some kind of repo through Cydia, you can set sudo as a dependency.

Comment: True, but if he releases the app through Cydia, he could easily install his app to `/Applications` and gain super user rights automatically, but this of course actually makes the whole original question useless.

Comment: WHat keeps you from adding him?

Comment: I disagree with Henri.  When installing an app with dpkg -i, although it install in /Applications, the app is runned under "mobile" user, even when chown root