# Xcode - Passing Bash Commands With A Jailbroken Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, bash, jailbreak, dpkg

I'd like to know how it would be possible to execute bash commands on a jailbroken iOS device with Xcode? I'm not bothered about the code signing process because I already have a developer account.

I've tried using these 2 commands:

```
system("cd /var/mobile/Documents");
system("mkdir myNewFolder");
```

But Xcode returns "Cannot create directory, permission denied".

I know for definite that this is possible. Basically, I want to be using commands such as dpkg and apt commands.

Thanks in advance,
Declan

Comment: You need to run commands as root Declan.

Comment: Ahh! Of course haha, thank you for that John! There's only one problem, how would I log in as root with a single command?

Comment: Updated with an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UNIX like OS's like iOS you can use the 'Sudo' command to run as root.

To use in one line you need to use UNIX pipes like this:

**system("echo yourPassword | sudo -S yourCommand");**

You need to make sure sudo is installed on your device, not sure if it is by default.

Some more info here: [On a jailbroken iPhone, how can I run commands as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516370/on-a-jailbroken-iphone-how-can-i-run-commands-as-root)